# Apply Background style to each page in intel xdk

Tags: html, cordova, intel-xdk

I need help with Intel XDK, How can I apply different Background style for each page. For now, when I select one background Style to the specific page, It automatically applies to every other page.

P.S, I am developing an app in Design mode.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it throw js , by changing the style of you body depend on rout/url 
if you use Angularjs for example it gonna be like that

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    containerClass: 'Homecss'
})
.state('otherpage', {
    url: '/otherpage',
    templateUrl: 'otherpage.html',
    controller: 'otherpageController',
    containerClass: 'otherpagecss'
})
```

then

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        $rootScope.containerClass = toState.containerClass;
    });
```

and in your html

```
<div ng-class="{{containerClass}}">...</div>
```

there is also angularjs modules help to make it easy like [angular-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-css)